# XSLT convert child node text to the parent's attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to use XSL to transform my XML document so that text values of certain child nodes become attributes of their parents.

Here's what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<property_data>
  <property>
    <property_descriptions>
      <property_description>
        <type>property</type>
        <description>property 1000 description</description>
      </property_description>
      <property_description>
        <type>rate</type>
        <description>text rate description</description>
      </property_description>
    </property_descriptions>
    <property_attributes>
      <property_id>1000</property_id>
    </property_attributes>
  </property>
    <property>
...
  </property>
</property_data>
```

And here's what I'm trying to achieve:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <property_data>
  <property>
    <property_descriptions>
      <property_description type="property">property 1000 description</property_description>
      <property_description type="rate">text rate description</property_descriptions>
    <property_attributes>
      <property_id>1000</property_id>
    </property_attributes>
  </property>
    <property>
...
  </property>
</property_data>
```

I'm stuck with the part where I need to select child's value.

**EDIT**:
Following michael.hor257k advice I was able to get the following .xsl that does the job:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="1.0">

    <!--Identity Transform.-->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="property_description">
        <property_description type="{type}">
            <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
        </property_description>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please post your current XSLT so we can fix it, instead of starting from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, together with the *identity transform* template, should provide the expected result:

```
<xsl:template match="property_description">
    <property_description type="{type}">
        <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
    </property_description>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Identity transform is when you match="node()|@* and then apply templates to the selected node?

Comment: @IngvarPetrov Identity transform is what you now have in your edited XSLT: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT